# How can I work with AMI via cURL?

Tags: linux, curl, asterisk, asteriskami

I have an asterisk server with AMI web enabled on port 8088, prefix `asterisk`. So my rawman url would be `http://myserver:8088/asterisk/rawman`

I just tried to login and ping with 2 urls 
`http://myserver:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=admin&secret=admin` 
`http://myserver:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=ping`

It works when I enter 2 above urls into the web browsers, but it does not when I use cURL from terminal.

Result from Terminal:
`curl 'http://myserver:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=admin&secret=admin'` 
`Response: Success`
`Message: Authentication accepted`

`curl 'http://myserver:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=ping'`
`Response: Error`
`Message: Permission denied`

Error from Asterisk CLI: (X.X.X.X is my LAN ip address)

```
HTTP Connect attempt from 'X.X.X.X' unable to authenticate
```

So I can not execute any further command like the way I did when dealing with AJAM. 
If anybody have an idea, please help me out, thank you.
Best Regards 
Loi Dang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your first request in browser you pass through authentication process and Asterisk respond with a cookie that your browser keeps and uses in further requests. You should see it in AMI response Set-Cookie header.

However that doesn't happen when you use cURL, it doesn't save the cookie for you. You should explicitly tell cURL to use the cookie in the request. Refer to cURL manual to find details http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html

OR

You can provide digest authentication for every single request with the alternate a* commands. For instance your ping action will look like this:

```
curl -v --digest -u admin:admin http://myserver:8088/asterisk/arawman?action=ping
```

Comment: Your fast and easy way (your 'OR') does not work for me, but the reference to 'http-cookies' do. Thank you very much @Misha

Answer (score 4):

Hate to answer my own question, but I post this for someone else who would get into this trouble

Reference to http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html in short:

Store the cookiejar when login:

> curl -c ./cookie-file -v
>   http://myserver:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=admin&secret=admin

Use the cookiejar with ping or other commands:

> curl -b ./cookie-file -v
>   http://myserver:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=ping

It should work.

Loi Dang

Comment: If asterisk returns "unable to autenticate" like it happened to me, use the double quotes in the curl command `curl -c ./cookie-file -v "http://myserver:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=admin&secret=admin"`

Answer (score 0):

curl -c /path/to/cookiefile http://yourhost/
to write to a cookie file and start engine and to use cookie you can use

curl -b /path/to/cookiefile  http://yourhost/**
its works for me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to fully explain your answer. Also please format your code as code `it should appear like this`.